# error with numpy while using opencv with python using some hash techniques to compare signatures

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

File "mtrand.pyx" line 1166, in mtrand.RandomState.choice ValueError : cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=false'

Comment: Can you post part of code which is causing the error?

Comment: You are asking us to imagine the code you have written and then tell you what might be causing the error message you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Without further info I guess you want a sample bigger than the array you're sampling from.

The only way to do that is [with replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(statistics)#Replacement_of_selected_units), so you need to enable it with `replace=True`.

*Note that while it's a perfectly legit sampling technique it might not be what you want and blindly enabling replacement may cover the real issue. It would be great if you could share more of the problematic code.*